# AngularJS SubMenu Highlighting

Tags: angularjs

I have a menu controller which looks like this:

```
apoSoft.controller("MenuCtrl", function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.menuClass = function(page) {
    var current = $location.path().substring(1);
    return page === current ? "active" : "";
  };
});
```

and a snippet of my menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-class="menuClass('usercreate')">
        <a href="#!/usercreate">Create User</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this works fine for main menu. but now what I would need is, that if I navigate to a submenu, than the related main menu should still be highlighted. 
I would need something like this:

```
...
<li ng-class="menuClass('usercreate or usercreateresponse')">
...
```

but this of course does not work.
Does anybody have any idea how I could solve this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than call that function many times all over the menu you could use one event listener to change a scope variable instead. I'm not sure what router you are using so will assume `ngRoute` for now

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(}(
    $scope.path = $location.path().substring(1);
});
```

Then within `ng-class` use object syntax

```
<li ng-class="{active: path=='usercreate' || path == 'usercreateresponse'}">
```